# Wordpress Custom Post Type not Showing in Appearance > Menu

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Yep, I have been searching all over, and seems the only reason this should be happening is because it is not checked in the Screen Options menu in WordPress. My problem is, the custom post type is not showing in Screen Options so I was wondering if someone could have a look at my code and see if I'm doing some thing wrong.

```
function my_custom_post_maryland() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Maryland', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Maryland', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Maryland page' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Maryland Page' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Page' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Page' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Pages' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Page' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Maryland Pages' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No Maryland pages found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Maryland pages found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Page' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Maryland'
);

$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Holds our Maryland pages specific data',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
    'show_ui'       => true,
    'has_archive'   => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true
);
register_post_type( 'maryland', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_maryland' );
```

Comment: I believe this is a caching issue. I cleared my browser cache and the options appeared.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to add it to the menu using

```
function setup_bonsai_theme_admin_menus()
{
    add_menu_page('MyTheme settings', 'My Theme Settings', 'manage_options', 
        'my_theme_settings', 'my_page_settings');

    add_submenu_page('my_theme_settings', 
        'My Page Elements', 'maryland', 'manage_options', 
        'my_questions_settings', 'my_maryland_settings');
}
```

and

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'setup_bonsai_theme_admin_menus');
```

and

```
function my_page_settings()
{
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h2>There are no theme options at this stage.</h2>
    </div>
    <?php

}

function my_maryland_settings()
{
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h2>Maryland</h2>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

After that you also need to add a new template file for single posts as well as archive posts, etc, so you can actually view them. The wordpress codex for 'theme templates' should help you there, as it's quite easy.

Comment: Tanks for the reply... but It is already showing in the menu below 'Posts'.  Do I need to create a settings page in order to have the custom post types to show in Appearance > Menus, so I can create menus for the front end?

Comment: No, you first have to create a page using the custom template. Once you create a template, then follow your new link to create a new custom page using that template, it should show up in you pages list so you can add it to the menu. I just did another one of these earlier this afternoon, and one yesterday, with the code above (yours and mine) plus the custom template, and it's working 100%. Look up http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates . If you don't come right I'll post all my code as an example for you to follow.

Comment: LEt me post anyway... a working example, then I'll delete this answer assuming it all works. Forgive the function names, I just copied from the earler site I was working on and changed the function content.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example.

functions.php

```
    <?php
    function setup_bonsai_theme_admin_menus()
    {
        add_menu_page('SCHS Theme settings', 'SCHS Theme Settings', 'manage_options', 
            'SCHS_theme_settings', 'SCHS_page_settings');

        add_submenu_page('SCHS_theme_settings', 
            'SCHS Page Elements', 'Questions', 'manage_options', 
            'SCHS_questions_settings', 'SCHS_questions_setings'); 
        add_submenu_page('SCHS_theme_settings', 
            'SCHS Page Elements', 'Answers', 'manage_options', 
            'SCHS_ansers_settings', 'SCHS_answers_settings'); 

    }

    function SCHS_page_settings()
    {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
        <h2>There are no theme options at this stage.</h2>
        </div>
        <?php

    }

    function SCHS_questions_setings()
    {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Questions</h2>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    function SCHS_answers_settings()
    {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Answers</h2>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    function question_custom_post()
    {
        $labels = array(
            'name'               => _x( 'Questions', 'post type general name' ),
            'singular_name'      => _x( 'Questions', 'post type singular name' ),
            'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Question' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Question' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'New Question' ),
            'all_items'          => __( 'All Questions' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Questions' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search Questions' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No question found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No question found in the trash' ), 
            'parent_item_colon'  => '',
            'menu_name'          => 'SCHS Questions'
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels'        => $labels,
            'description'   => 'Holds our questions and question specific data',
            'public'        => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'has_archive'   => true,
        );
        register_post_type( 'question', $args );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'question_custom_post' );
    add_action('admin_menu', 'setup_bonsai_theme_admin_menus');
    ?>

single-question.php

    <?php
    /**
     * The template for displaying questions and answers
     *
     * @package WordPress
     * @subpackage SCHS
     * @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
     */
    get_header();
    ?>
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
                    </header>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <nav id="nav-single">
                            <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'catchbox' ); ?></h3>
                            <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'catchbox' ) ); ?></span>
                            <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'catchbox' ) ); ?></span>
                        </nav><!-- #nav-single -->
                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                    wp_reset_query();
                    the_content();
                    ?>
                </article>
            </main>
        </div>
        </div><!-- #primary -->
    <?php
    get_sidebar();
    get_footer();
    ?>
SCHS-questions.php
<?php
/*
    Template Name: SCHS Questions
    Description: This part is optional, but helpful for describing the Post Template
*/
get_header();
?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <header class="entry-header">
                <span id="schs-ask-a-question">Ask a question</span>
                <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content">
            <?php
                the_content();
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'question','posts_per_page' =>0,'paged' => $paged,'orderby'=>'title','order'=>'asc');
                $myposts = query_posts($args);
                ?>
                <fieldset id="schs-question-list">
                <legend>The Questions</legend>
                <ul>
                <?php
                foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                <li class="main_question_list_item">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->id);?>">
                    <span  class="question_class"><?php the_title();?></span><br/>
                    <!--
                    <?php $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);?>
                    <?php $grower = $custom["tree_grower"][0];?>
                    <span class="grower_name"><?php echo $grower;?></span>
                    -->
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
                </fieldset>
                <?php
            ?>
            </div>
        </article>
        </main>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that.. particularly the template part.. I had other post types to add so I went ahead and created another one, very much the same as the one in my original post, but this new one shows in Appearance > Menus no problem.  So I have copied duplicated that one and edited it for the Maryland one.  (Code Below). I still cant figure out why the original one was not showing the in Apprearance > Menus section of wp-admin, probably a comma or something i just cant see lol.. the usual stuff!

Comment: Yeah, a head slapping moment when you find it. Best be is to add wp_debug(true); to the beginning so it will help find any php bugs. Glad it's working for you now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to [register the men](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu)u in your functions.php in theme:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );

function register_my_menu() {
   register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'theme-slug' ) );
}
```

Comment: The menus were being used in widgets, so was no need to register any more menus (I think 30 menus is enough lol (siloing)). Thanks for the reply tho.

Answer (score -1):

```
function pb_custom_post_cases() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Recent Cases', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Recent Case', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'case' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Case' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Case' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Case' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Cases' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Cases' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Cases' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No cases found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No cases found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Recent Cases'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our recent cases specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'cases', 'with_front'=> false)
    );
    register_post_type( 'cases', $args );   
}
add_action( 'init', 'pb_custom_post_cases' );

/* Taxonomy Recent cases */
function my_taxonomies_cases() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Case Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Case Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Case Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Case Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Case Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Case Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Case Category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Case Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Case Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Case Category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Case Categories' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'cases_category', 'cases', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_cases', 0 );

/* Custom Messages - Recent Cases */

function pb_cases_updated_messages( $messages ) {
    global $post, $post_ID;
    $messages['cases'] = array(
        0 => '', 
        1 => sprintf( __('Recent Case Updated. <a href="%s">View case</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
        2 => __('Custom field updated.'),
        3 => __('Custom field deleted.'),
        4 => __('Case updated.'),
        5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf( __('Case restored to revision from %s'), wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
        6 => sprintf( __('Recent Case published. <a href="%s">View Case</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
        7 => __('Product saved.'),
        8 => sprintf( __('Case submitted. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview case</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
        9 => sprintf( __('Case scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>. <a target="_blank" href="%2$s">Preview case</a>'), date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i' ), strtotime( $post->post_date ) ), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
        10 => sprintf( __('RecentCase draft updated. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview case</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
    );
    return $messages;
}
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'pb_cases_updated_messages' );
```